# Visualg - Resultado Booleano

Tags: algoritmo, condição, visualg

Eu montei esse algoritmo no Visualg:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
inicio
se 3 = "a" entao
   escreva("igual")
senao
   escreva("diferente")
FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

E não entendi, por que a condição está retornando como verdadeira?

Comment: Retorna verdadeira ou rertorna `v`?

Comment: A sua lógica está correta, seria para retornar Falso, porém retorna verdadeiro por um motivo desconhecido, eu baixei a última versão do VisualG para poder testar e notei esta incoerência também, porém eu testei no shell do python e funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Retorna "v" porque você escreveu sua condição assim. Você inverteu a lógica, colocou pra retornar "v" quando a condição for falsa.

Comment: Não eu quis dizer por que a condição "se" retorna a condição verdadeira e não o comando escreva "v", no visualg ele executa o comando escreva "f".

Answer (score 1):

Eu testei o teu código com algumas alterações e outros valores, porém o resultado continua recebendo um valor booleano 'Verdadeiro' e imprimindo na tela valor **IGUAL**: Observe...

```
 algoritmo "semnome"
 var
   x: inteiro
 inicio
   x <- 8
   se x = "c" entao
      escreva("igual")
   senao
      escreva("diferente")
   fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Acredito que seja bug, mesmo que o valor de x está recebendo o valor c mesmo sendo a variável declarado seja inteiro.